# How to use a select result in another sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

In a SQL*Plus script I want to use the result of

```
select SUBSTR(file_name, 0, INSTR(file_name,'\',-1,1)) 
   into :oradataPath 
from dba_data_files where ROWNUM = 1;
```

in the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE DEMO DATAFILE '&oradataPath\DEMO.DBF';
```

but SQL*Plus asks me for the value of `oradataPath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need dynamic sql; for example:

```
declare
  vOradataPath varchar2(100);
  vSQL         varchar2(1000);
begin
  select SUBSTR(file_name, 0, INSTR(file_name,'\',-1,1)) 
   into vOradataPath 
  from dba_data_files
  where ROWNUM = 1;
  --
  vSQl := 'CREATE TABLESPACE DEMO DATAFILE ''' || vOradataPath || '\DEMO.DBF''';
  execute immediate vSQL;
end;
```